# Spring JPA + MongoDB AbstractMethodError

Tags: mysql, spring, mongodb, maven, jpa

Trying to create a Spring application that writes both in a MongoDB and in a MySQL. I am using JPA, Hibernate, Maven for this project. The application basically executes two methods:

one to write in a MongoDB (works)

and

one to write into MySQL (not working)

The writing into MongoDB works. But the MySQL part does not.
I could not get the cross-store to work, that is why i am trying to do it "manually"
**getting following error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.jcg.examples.test.Application.main(Application.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:171)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:239)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:225)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 12 more
```

Here are the files:

**Pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SpringDataMongoDbExample</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringDataMongoDbExample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>

        </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I created two different **Spring config files** with different names:

**spring-jpa-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">


 <jpa:repositories base-package="com.jcg.examples.jpa.repo"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springDataJPA"/>
        <property name="username" value=""/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
        <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <!-- spring based scanning for entity classes-->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.jcg.examples.entity"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

**spring-mongo-config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
          xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
          xsi:schemaLocation=
          "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Default bean name is 'mongo' -->
    <mongo:mongo id="mongo" host="localhost" port="27017"/>

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongo"/>
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="jcg"/>
  </bean>

    <mongo:repositories base-package="com.jcg.examples.mongo.repo"></mongo:repositories>

</beans>
```

Entity written into MySQL
**Employee.java:**

```
package com.jcg.examples.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "dept")
    private String dept;

    public Employee() {

    }

    public Employee(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String dept) {
        this.setId(id);
        this.setFirstName(firstName);
        this.setLastName(lastName);
        this.setDept(dept);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getDept() {
        return dept;
    }

    public void setDept(String dept) {
        this.dept = dept;
    }
}
```

Document written into MongoDB:
**Person.java:**

```
package com.jcg.examples.entity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.PersistenceConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.DBRef;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection="person")
public class Person
{

        @Id
        private Long personId;

        private String name;

        private int age;

        @DBRef(db="address")
        private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();

        public Person()
        {}


        @PersistenceConstructor
        public Person(Long personId, String name, int age)
        {
                super();
                this.personId = personId;
                this.name = name;
                this.age = age;
        }

        public Long getPersonId()
        {
                return personId;
        }

        public void setPersonId(Long personId)
        {
                this.personId = personId;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
                return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name)
        {
                this.name = name;
        }

        public int getAge()
        {
                return age;
        }

        public void setAge(int age)
        {
                this.age = age;
        }

        public List<Address> getAddresses()
        {
                return addresses;
        }


        public void setAddresses(List<Address> addresses)
        {
                this.addresses = addresses;
        }


        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
                return "Person [personId=" + personId + ", name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", addresses=" + addresses + "]";
        }



}
```

Repo for Employee
**EmployeeRepo.java:**

```
package com.jcg.examples.jpa.repo;


import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.jcg.examples.entity.Employee;

public interface EmployeeRepo extends CrudRepository<Employee, Integer> {

    public List<Employee> searchByfirstName(String firstName);

}
```

Document written in MongoDB: 
**Address.java:**

```
package com.jcg.examples.entity;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.PersistenceConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection="address")
public class Address
{

        @Id
        private long addressId;

        private String address;

        private String city;

        private String state;

        private long zipcode;

        public Address()
        {

                System.out.println("CAlling default cons");
        }

        @PersistenceConstructor
        public Address(long addressId, String address, String city, String state, long zipcode)
        {
                super();
                this.addressId = addressId;
                this.address = address;
                this.city = city;
                this.state = state;
                this.zipcode = zipcode;
        }




        public String getAddress()
        {
                return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(String address)
        {
                this.address = address;
        }

        public String getCity()
        {
                return city;
        }

        public void setCity(String city)
        {
                this.city = city;
        }

        public String getState()
        {
                return state;
        }

        public void setState(String state)
        {
                this.state = state;
        }

        public long getZipcode()
        {
                return zipcode;
        }

        public void setZipcode(long zipcode)
        {
                this.zipcode = zipcode;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
                return "Address [address=" + address + ", city=" + city + ", state=" + state + ", zipcode=" + zipcode + "]";
        }




}
```

Repo for Person **PersonRepo.java:**

```
package com.jcg.examples.mongo.repo;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.jcg.examples.entity.Person;

public interface PersonRepo extends CrudRepository<Person, Long>
{
        @Query("{'name' : ?0}")
        public Iterable<Person> searchByName(String personName);

}
```

Repo for Address
**AddressRepo.java:**

```
package com.jcg.examples.mongo.repo;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.jcg.examples.entity.Address;

public interface AddressRepo extends CrudRepository<Address, Long>
{
}
```

the **Main Application** for testing:

```
package com.jcg.examples.test;


import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.jcg.examples.entity.Employee;
import com.jcg.examples.entity.Address;
import com.jcg.examples.entity.Person;
import com.jcg.examples.jpa.repo.EmployeeRepo;
import com.jcg.examples.mongo.repo.AddressRepo;
import com.jcg.examples.mongo.repo.PersonRepo;


public class Application


{       private static CrudRepository repository;
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new ClassPathResource("spring-mongo-config.xml").getPath());
                PersonRepo personRepo = context.getBean(PersonRepo.class);
                AddressRepo addressRepo = context.getBean(AddressRepo.class);

                Person personAchilles = new Person();
                personAchilles.setPersonId(1l);
                personAchilles.setName("Achilles");
                personRepo.save(personAchilles);
                Person personHektor = new Person();
                personHektor.setPersonId(2l);
                personHektor.setName("Hektor");

                Address address = new Address(1,"221b Baker Street","London NW1","London",12345l);
                List<Address> addresses = personHektor.getAddresses();
                addresses.add(address);
                personAchilles.setAddresses(addresses);             

                addressRepo.save(address);
                personRepo.save(personHektor);

                Iterable<Person> personList = personRepo.findAll();
                System.out.println("Person List : ");
                for (Person person : personList)
        {
                System.out.println(person);
        }

                System.out.println("Person with Id 1 is "+personRepo.searchByName("Hektor"));

                context.close();

                //THIS IS THE JPA PART============================================

                ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context1 = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-jpa-config.xml");
                repository = context1.getBean(EmployeeRepo.class);

                createEmployee(22, "Saint", "Peter", "Engineering");
                createEmployee(23, "Jack", " Dorsey", "Imaginea");
                createEmployee(24, "Sam", "Fox", "Imaginea");

                context1.close();

        }

            private static void createEmployee(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String dept) {

                Employee emp = new Employee(id, firstName, lastName, dept);
                repository.save(emp);
            }


}
```

What is weird is that in the **spring-jpa-config.xml**  Eclipse marks certain keywords with the blue waved underlining (see screenshot):
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

here is the application folder structure:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I tried using the GOSLING release for my pom
**new POM.xml:**

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SpringDataMongoDbExample</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringDataMongoDbExample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>



    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring-data.version>Gosling-RELEASE</spring-data.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-data.version}</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

as a result i got this error:

```
Person List : 
Person [personId=1, name=Achilles, age=0, addresses=[]]
Person [personId=2, name=Hektor, age=0, addresses=[Address [address=221b Baker Street, city=London NW1, state=London, zipcode=12345]]]
Person with Id 1 is [Person [personId=2, name=Hektor, age=0, addresses=[Address [address=221b Baker Street, city=London NW1, state=London, zipcode=12345]]]]
Apr 07, 2016 4:07:50 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
Apr 07, 2016 4:07:50 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.10.Final}
Apr 07, 2016 4:07:50 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Apr 07, 2016 4:07:50 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Apr 07, 2016 4:07:50 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Thu Apr 07 16:07:50 PDT 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Apr 07, 2016 4:07:51 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [spring-jpa-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1045)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:824)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.jcg.examples.test.Application.main(Application.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:973)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:824)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3845)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3799)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1412)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: an AbstractMethodError tells you what is the method in question. Update your post with the full details. Even from that listing MongoDB is nothing to do with it, since you aren't using JPA with that

Comment: i just updated the question. The complete error is listed above.

Comment: You are mixing different versions of Spring Data. Spring Data JPA 1.9.4 has requires a different Spring Data Common then Spring Data MongoDB 1.7.2. I strongly suggest using the [release BOM](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/bom/pom.xml) instead of individual versions of parts of Spring Data. You want either latest Gosling release or the newly released Hopper one.